# Why does importing a SystemJS module fail in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, systemjs

I have a React application that I try to import a module registered as a SystemJS module using the following code snippet.

```
import System from 'systemjs';
const imported_module;

System.import("https://example.js")
    .then((module) => {
      // Use the module
      imported_module = module;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error loading the module:', error);
    });
```

However, when I try to import it I get the following error even though I have installed systemjs npm module.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-node.cjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/node_modules/systemjs/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-node.cjs 7785:17-30
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Can anybody figure out what am I doing wrong here?